# CS50W - Network - Like Button working but Like count is not updating

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am currently working on Project4 from CS50W.
The task is to write a social media like site where users can post, follow and like.

I have implemented a like button to every post (which is wokring fine) unfortunately I have to refresh the page for the like to show. I whould rather want the like to update directly after clicking the like button.

I am creating the div for the posts via Javascript and calling the like_post function onclick

```
function load_posts() {

  // get posts from /posts API Route
  fetch('/all_posts')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(posts => {

    // create a div element for each post
    posts.forEach(post => {
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = "card post-card";
        div.innerHTML = `
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">${post['username']}</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">${post['timestamp']}</h6>
          <p class="card-text">${post['text']}</p>
          <button class="card-text like-button" onclick="like_post(${post.id});"><h3> ♥ </button> </h3>
          ${post['likes']}
        </div> 
        `;
        // append div to posts-view
        document.querySelector('#posts-view').append(div);
    });
  });
}

function like_post(post_id) {
  fetch('/post/' + post_id, {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        like: true
    })
  });
}
```

this is my view funtion to handle most post related requests

```
@csrf_exempt
@login_required
def post(request, post_id):
    
    # Query for requested post
    try:
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
    except Post.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({"error": "Post not found."}, status=404)

    # Return post contents
    if request.method == "GET":
        return JsonResponse(post.serialize())

    # Update likes
    elif request.method == "PUT":
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        if data.get("like") is not None and data.get("like") is True:
            if post.likes.filter(username=user.username).exists():
                post.likes.remove(User.objects.get(username=user.username))
            else: 
                post.likes.add(User.objects.get(username=user.username))
            return HttpResponse(status=204)
        
    # Post must be via GET or PUT
    else:
        return JsonResponse({
            "error": "GET or PUT request required."
        }, status=400)
```

I wanted to add a `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))` or `return redirect(reverse('index'))`
underneath the post.like.add and post.like.remove to redirect to the current page, but this makes the
`return HttpResponse(status=204)` unreachable which results in this error:

```
Forbidden (CSRF token missing.): /
[28/Mar/2023 22:35:55] "PUT / HTTP/1.1" 403 2506
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the like count using javascript, very similar to how you render the original `Post` Divs, with very little modifications!

### View

return the Post's Pk and the Like count instead of `HttpResponse(status=204)` for the PUT block

I also removed that `try` and that `User` get(), I've added comments explaining why

```py
@csrf_exempt
@login_required
def post(request, post_id):

    # Try's are icky!
    post = Post.objects.filter(pk=post_id).first()
    if post is None:
        return JsonResponse({"error": "Post not found."}, status=404)

    # request.user is already a User object!
    user = request.user

    # Return post contents
    if request.method == "GET":
        return JsonResponse(post.serialize())

    # Update likes
    elif request.method == "PUT":
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        if data.get("like") is not None and data.get("like") is True:
            if post.likes.filter(username=user.username).exists():
                post.likes.remove(User.objects.get(username=user.username))
            else:
                post.likes.add(User.objects.get(username=user.username))
            # \/ Post's pk and the total number of likes
            return JsonResponse({'pk':post.pk,'like_count':post.likes.all().count()})
```

### Javascript

#### load_posts()

Now this requires a **small** update to your `load_posts`:

- wrapping the Like Count in a span
- add the Post's pk embedded as an attribute in the span `pk='{{pk}}'`

Both of these will let you easily fetch that specific span in the next section

**Note:** I'm assuming your returning the 'pk' for each post in `/all_posts`, do this if you aren't already

```js
function load_posts() {

  // get posts from /posts API Route
  fetch('/all_posts')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(posts => {

    // create a div element for each post
    posts.forEach(post => {
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = "card post-card";
        div.innerHTML = `
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">${post['username']}</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">${post['timestamp']}</h6>
          <p class="card-text">${post['text']}</p>
          <button class="card-text like-button" onclick="like_post(${post.id});"><h3> ♥ </button> </h3>
          <span class="like-count" pk="${post['pk']}">${post['likes']}</span>
        </div> 
        `;
        // append div to posts-view
        document.querySelector('#posts-view').append(div);
    });
  });
}
```

#### like_post()

This is the easy part.

1. Use the Pk in the reponse data to fetch the correct span
2. Update the inner HTML to the new count

```js
function like_post(post_id) {
  fetch('/post/' + post_id, {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        like: true
    })
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    // get the span
    span = document.querySelectorAll('span[pk="'+data['pk']+'"]');
    // update the contents
    span.innerHTML = data['like_count'];
  })
}
```

### Fin

and just like that the count should update when you click the button!

**PS:** i have **NO** idea why you could be getting a `CSRF token missing` error when adding the refresh/redirect to a `@csrf_exempt` page.. maybe it has something to do with the `@login_required`?- very odd!

---

#### Edit

Sorry, I usually do JQuery not Vanilla Javascript- I should have tested it Locally.

`span = document.querySelectorAll('span[pk="'+data['pk']+'"]');` needs to be -> `span = document.querySelectorAll('span.like-count[pk="'+data['pk']+'"]')[0];`

Here's how I debugged it tho, just so you know the steps

```js
  .then(data => {
    // get the span
    span = document.querySelectorAll('span[pk="'+data['pk']+'"]');

    // add output to make sure it's fetching the span 
    console.log(span);  // <----

    // update the contents
    span.innerHTML = data['like_count'];
  })
```

It outputted: (an Array)

```js
NodeList [ span.like-count ]
```

So easy fix, just grab the first item!
I also added `span.like-count` in the Selecter, it should have always been like that, it's more exact.

Usually when you use JQuery, it just *knows* to grab that first item (forgot that was a thing!) Look into using JQuery, it's very convenient!

Comment: hey thanks alot for the quick answer!!!

I dont know whats going on here, it's still not working :( I did everything you suggested. and checked more than twice. I checked with console.log(data['like_count']) 
which is showing the right count, but the span is not updating somehow. 
I don't get an error either.

Comment: My bad! I made an edit. I was **so** close, but no cigar- it's always *something* I swear

Comment: Great! finally it's wokring, Thank you so much!!

Just one thing span.like-count is not working for me as a selector. I am still using span like you suggested before.

Comment: You could just use the class in selector, same diff: `.like-count` ..but I'm not 100% why it wouldn't work to.. just open up the Developer Console and fiddle around: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/ or `CTRL-SHIFT-C` on Firefox (great thing to use if you aren't already)